# kafka producer using Rest API

Tags: rest, apache-kafka

We are trying to build a data-torrent application using kafka as a source that will consume messages from web UI using REST.
Can someone provide a good documentation or some steps how to setup kafka produce using java REST API ?

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to post messages to a Kafka topic using a REST API, if I understand correctly?

Comment: http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/index.html

Answer (score 5):

Check out [kafka-rest](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest).

It will let you produce messages to a Kafka topic with a REST API in JSON or Avro. It is in Java and you may be able to use it out-of-the-box if you don't have special requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you don't want to use [Confluent REST Proxy for Kafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest), you can run a web application using a [Web Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_framework) which will call into a [Kafka Client](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients) library during an HTTP request from the client.